# How to do Panoramic wallpaper in ViewPager in android ?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, wallpaper

I want to add panoramic effect on my ViewPager, i have one ViewPager and i have set the background of that ViewPager but i want Panoramic effect to that background wallpaper, suppose if i'll slide the ViewPager then the portion of that wallpaper also should move.

Please kindly suggest me some solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported *out of the box.*

There're several possible implementations(extensions of ViewPager) which you can use instead. One of them is https://github.com/andraskindler/parallaxviewpager

[image]